# Akka supervisor catch future Failure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-supervision

I'm trying to develop an application using Futures and Akka supervisors but when A future returns a Failure to an actor its supervisor is not getting the exception.

Here's my code.

1) Supervisor actor

```
class TransaccionActorSupervisor() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val actor: ActorRef = context.actorOf(Props[TransaccionActor].withRouter(RoundRobinPool(nrOfInstances = 5)), "transaccion-actor")

  def receive = {
    case msg: Any => actor forward msg
  }

  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
    case exception =>
      println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< IN SUPERVISOR >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>")
      Restart
  }

}
```

Supervised actor

```
Class TransaccionActor() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val _: ExecutionContext = context.dispatcher
  val transaccionAdapter = (new TransaccionComponentImpl with TransaccionRepositoryComponentImpl).adapter

  def receive = {

    case msg: GetTransaccionById =>
      val currentSender: ActorRef = sender()
      transaccionAdapter.searchTransaction(msg.id).onComplete {
         case Success(transaction) => currentSender ! transaction
         case Failure(error) => throw error
      }

  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and Ryan's answer did help. But because I'm new to Akka it was not trivial to understand the answer so I would like to provide some details.

First, I think that `onComplete` will not work at all. It just registers the callback function which may be called in a completely separate thread and does not return a new `Future`. So any exception thrown within `onComplete` will be lost.

Instead, it is better to use `map`, `recover`, `recoverWith` or `transform` as they return new `Future`s. Then you need to the pipe the result to an actor, e.g. `self`; the receiving actor has to process the piped result and rethrow the exception.

In other words your supervised actor should look like this:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe
import akka.actor.Status.Failure
import akka.actor.Actor

class TransaccionActor() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  import context.dispatcher

  val transaccionAdapter = 
    (new TransaccionComponentImpl with TransaccionRepositoryComponentImpl).adapter

  def receive = {

    case msg: GetTransaccionById =>
      val currentSender: ActorRef = sender()
      transaccionAdapter searchTransaction msg.id map { transaction =>
         currentSender ! transaction
      } pipeTo self

    case Failure(throwable) => throw throwable

  }

}
```

Comment: This was exactly the same issue I was facing just now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions thrown in a future within an actor are not caught by the actor.  You'll need to pipe the exception to `self` and then re-throw if you want it handled by the supervising actor.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. Could you please explain your answer in more detail, preferably with a code snippet?